# Nohup no such file or directory with Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute a playbook that will execute sql script on 4 different databases.

In the playbook, I am using the command as

```yaml
- name: Run sample script
  shell: nohup ./S4D/wrapper.sh ./S4D/sample.sql > ./S4D/nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

The directory structure looks like

```
root/
└── SD4/
    ├── wrapper.sh
    └── sample.sql
```

I am getting the error

> "stderr" : "/bin/sh: ./S4D/nohup.out: No such file or directory"

already checked EOL conversion, set to Unix (LF).

Comment: If the directory structure is /S4D/Wrapper.sh then just give the same inside nohup command also. Not sure ur current directory(dot) refers to wherever the play is running. As you know the full path, just give that and try.

Comment: The requirement is to have 4 directories corresponding to each of my 4 databases. Each Directory will have sql scripts and a wrapper.sh which sets the TNS_ADMIN and provides the database name and credentials for connection. A single playbook will have 4 tasks , using shell module to run these sql scripts on databases using nohup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure of where the task is going to execute, you can use the [`chdir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-chdir) parameter of the `shell` module:

```yaml
- name: Run sample script
  shell: nohup wrapper.sh sample.sql > nohup.out 2>&1 & 
  args:
    chdir: /SD4
    ## chdir: /root/SD4
    ##   ^--- since I am not sure from your question 
    ##          if root is / or
    ##          if it is the /root folder
```

Comment: chdir: <full path to S4D> , Inside S4D my wrapper and sql script is present, there is no error while executing the playbook, nohup.out is generated inside S4D, but it says "failed to run command wrapper_sample.sh : No such file or directory."

Comment: Is `wrapper_sample.sh` executable?

Comment: yes it is , the command (nohup wrapper_sample.sh sample.sql & ) itself works from the terminal. Infact all the variations with relative paths, absolute paths work fine. It just does not work with Ansible.